# The need for an app server in FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

*I don't know why i have to make app server for FCM*

Actually, I made app server for FCM.

But, I can send notification using FCM console.

Then, Why do i make an app server for FCM?

How do i profitably use app server in FCM ?

Comment: you can not send data with the notification from the console

Comment: no need for app server as u can just use cloud functions

Comment: @Badr  I sent data with the notification from the console. I used 'Advanced Option' tab and set key, value. I know that i can not send data without notification from the console.

Comment: @Peter Haddad   Can you tell me usage of app server for FCM? Like as 'Data analytic' or 'send specific token'

Comment: @HEEJAECHOI: If the messages you want to send can be sent from the Firebase console, you can stick to that and won't need an app server. If the messages cannot be sent from the Firebase console, you will need to run your own code to send messages. This code will in that case need access to the server key of your Firebase project. As its name implies, this key should only be used on a server you control or in an otherwise trusted environment, such as Cloud Functions.

Comment: Instead of asking us for use-cases for an app server, I recommend that you think of what you want to accomplish with Firebase Cloud Messaging. If you describe that, we can likely answer if this can be done through the console or if it requires custom server-side code (and thus an app server or Cloud Functions).

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen Thank you for your detailed answer!! First i just made app server for send messages. Although the messages i want to send can be sent from the Firebase console, i have purpose of studying. And, i think i can use device token for analytic. Like this, i want to know  simplicity cases how i can use app server. Thank you :)